# Changing a unix timestamp to a formatted date?

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix-timestamp, valueconverter

I currently have a unix timestamp and would like to change it into something more user friendly like instead of "1389317006" I would want "Jan. 10, 2014 13:45".  I looked into `strtotime()` but the PHP Manual said it returns a timestamp which isn't what I want.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [date](http://www.php.net/date) function:

```
echo date("M. d, Y H:i", 1389317006);
// Prints: Jan. 10, 2014 01:23
```